# Is this coverage problem NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete

Consider a set of K sensors which have a sensing disc of fixed diameter. We can put sensors on any point within the area. We are interested to deploy all these sensors in an area $A$, such that the total covered area is maximized.  Can we say this problem is NP-hard/NP-complete by using NP-completeness of Maximum Coverage Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem)?

Comment: maybe this page [on tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation#Introduction_to_tessellations) is more appropriate ; a regular tessellation with the same motif is not hard unless you introduce  constrains

Comment: By [Theorem 1.2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717110800033), for _fixed_ K, that will be in [NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)). ​ Also, see the Covering section of [Erich's packing center](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

How are you specifying the region $A$?  How do you specify the point where you put a sensor?  Without more details on how you make this a discrete problem, I don't think "NP-hard" or "NP-complete" are applicable.  In any case, the Maximum coverage problem you referenced is a discrete graph-theory problem, and it's not at all clear that these can be reduced to your problem of covering by discs, so NP-completeness of Maximum coverage does not say 
that this problem is NP-hard or NP-complete.

Comment: Region A for example can be a square. Sensors are allowed to move to any point on A.

Comment: Do you know how can I prove NP-hardness when dealing with continuous problems?

Comment: "For example" is not enough.  You have to specify exactly what regions are allowed.